# How to register strongly-typed SignalR Core hubs?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, autofac, asp.net-core-signalr

I have a ASP.Net Core 3.1 web app and I'm trying to inject strongly-typed hubs into the controller as follows:

```
public class MyController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IHubContext<MyHub, IMyHub> hubContext;

    public MyController(IHubContext<MyHub, IMyHub> hubContext)
    {
        this.hubContext = hubContext;
    }    
}
```

Autofac is already set up but I still didn't find a way to inject the hubs. (Versions or class SignalR had a `RegisterHubs` extension method.

I tried the following:

```
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes()
            .Where(t => typeof(IHubContext<>).IsAssignableFrom(t))
            .ExternallyOwned();
```

and this:

```
       builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes()
            .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Hub"))
            .As(typeof(Hub<>))
            .ExternallyOwned();
```

But it didn't work.

What is the new way to do it?

Comment: *Autofac is already set up* .. so you able to get autofac to work with other types?

Comment: @BrettCaswell Yes. I register my Automapper module, Logger, UoW and repositories. The next step was the hubs (converted to SignalR Core)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `AsClosedTypesOf(Hub<>)` instead of just `As(Hub<>)`. [See docs here.](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/scanning.html#specifying-services)

Comment: Now I can see that the hubs are being added to the container. However the error does still occur. Does `IHubContext` need to be registered too?

Comment: "The error" doesn't tell me what the error is. Update your question with the actual error info. Also, [have you read the docs?](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/signalr.html)

Comment: I dived deeper into the debug logs and noticed that the problem was because the Hub methods must return Task, no void. Also, there is no need to register any hubs with Autofac.